# Local functions not working in VueUse useWebWorkerFn

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-worker

I'm trying to filter an array of objects using `useWebWorkerFn`
The following is my code to do the same

```
import { useWebWorkerFn } from '@vueuse/core'
import { doLowerCase } from './filtering.js'

async function asyncDataSearch(data,searchWords) {

  const { workerFn } = useWebWorkerFn(dataSearch, {
    dependencies: [
      'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash-es@4.17.21/every.js',
      'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash-es@4.17.21/includes.js'
    ],
  })
  const filteredData = await workerFn(data, searchWords)
  return filteredData
}

async function dataSearch(data, searchWords) {

  return data.filter((e) => {
    let isTrueName = true;
    if (searchWords.length > 0) {
      const myBigStr = doLowerCase(
      .trim(
      `${e.fname}${e.lname} ${e.cname}`
      );

      isTrueName = _.every(searchWords, (el) => _.includes(myBigStr, el));
    }

    return isTrueName;

  });

}
```

And the below is the doLowerCase function in `filtering.js` file.

```
export function doLowerCase(myText = "") {
  if (myText) {
    return myText.toLowerCase();
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Now the problem is the lodash functions works when I add the lodash.min.js cdn url but I don't want to import the whole lodash package, when I try to add dependencies of each function as stated [here](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/lodash). It shows an error that it failed to import the scripts. Also in the above code `doLowerCase` is an function present in another file, the function is not working as it is not accessible, how do I import and use the function as expected. Fore more info visit [VueUse](https://vueuse.org/core/usewebworkerfn/)

Comment: Please show how you're importing the `lodash` functions. Also show `filtering.js`.

Comment: @tony19 I have updated the code as per your comment.